# TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having this problem in my layout, but I think that it's because I can't use var in my class Controller and I don't know if i'm declaring fine, but I'm not sure so please I aprecciate your help, and everyone have a nice day[image: Error]

[image: I guess that it should be a double]
[image: This is the lane that mark error, but I think that it's ok]

Comment: Nice that there is a method local variable with that name, it is ofcourse not in the model (you named it `Saldo Total`.

Comment: wow thank you so much, it's already fixed hehe

Comment: Please add your solution as the answer, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The error is in the class controller, in model.addAttribute
inside the quotes, it must be exactly as the layout: model.addAttribute("saldoTotal", saldoTotal);

And this is how it looks at the end

[image]